# How to handle DTMF on outcall using call files in asterisk?

Tags: asterisk

I'm making an outdial using call files in asterisk and application needs some DTMF input but DTMF not working for all mobile phones, It is not accepting digits from Nokia - 1100 and nokia 6030 where DTMF works if i make an incoming callfrom the same phone but on out dial using DTMF log i can see following messsage on asterisk CLI:

- DTMF Begin '1' received on Dahdi-32
- DTMF Begin ignored '1' on Dahdi-32

If someone knows the solution for this please let me know.

It works if i set overlapdial=no but in this case it doesn't make two simultaneous outdial on two different numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting relaxdtmf=true in the chan_dahdi.conf file?